# Open new window on center of screen with this javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, popup, popupwindow

My experience with javascript is extraordinarily limited. I would like to have the new window open up in the center of the screen.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fbs_click() {
var twtTitle = document.title;
var twtUrl = location.href;
var maxLength = 140 - (twtUrl.length + 1);
if (twtTitle.length > maxLength) {
    twtTitle = twtTitle.substr(0, (maxLength - 3)) + '...';
}
var twtLink = 'http://twitter.com/home?status=' + encodeURIComponent(twtTitle + ' ' + twtUrl);
window.open(twtLink,'','width=300,height=300'); } </script>
```

If somebody can please update my code to accomplish a popup window which is centered that would be amazing!

Comment: Popup windows are generally a bad idea. If you can do it another way (a box that expands in the page, for example) then that is usually a better choice.

Comment: What about fancybox? Would that be easy enough to integrate my existing code with?

Comment: So did my answer work for you in the end?

Comment: I tried inserting your provided code into a new <script type="text/javascript"> ... </script> and replacing window.open(twtLink,'','width=300,height=300'); with MyPopUpWin(300, 300); however this returns an "Object not Found! page. What am i doing wrong? Thanks. Pia @NickW

Comment: Call it as `MyPopUpWin(twtLink, 300, 300);` - the change is that the url is the first argument. Be sure that you are using the most recent version of the code.

Comment: I attempted the updated code: 
`function twitter_click() {
    var twtTitle = document.title;
    var twtUrl = location.href;
    var maxLength = 140 - (twtUrl.length + 1);
    if (twtTitle.length > maxLength) {
        twtTitle = twtTitle.substr(0, (maxLength - 3)) + '...';
    }
    var twtLink = 'http://twitter.com/home?status=' + encodeURIComponent(twtTitle + ' ' + twtUrl);
    MyPopUpWin(twtLink, 300, 300);
}`

Comment: and `function MyPopUpWin(url, width, height) {
    var leftPosition, topPosition;
    //Allow for borders.
    leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - (width + 10);
    //Allow for title and status bars.
    topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - (height + 50);
    //Open the window.
    window.open(url, "Window2",
    "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width+ ",resizable=yes,left="
    + iMyWidth + ",top=" + iMyHeight + ",screenX=" + iMyWidth + ",screenY="
    + iMyHeight + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no");
}` but this does not load :( @NickW

Comment: Can you post the contents of `twtLink` when you call `MyPopUpWin`?

Comment: Sorry, I must have been asleep when I coded that. Try this latest version.

Comment: Using the above code when i click on the twitter button that calls twitter_click() nothing appears to happen. Is this what you mean? @NickW

Comment: Don't worry about the content of `twtLink`, my code was wrong anyway (it should be correct now, though).

Comment: Oh fantastic! That works exactly perfect now! Thanks so much for your help. :) Pia @NickW

Comment: Curious, am I wrong in remembering that about 10 years ago, you could center a popup by using -1 as a value for something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How's this (adapted from [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=2296)):

```
function MyPopUpWin(url, width, height) {
    var leftPosition, topPosition;
    //Allow for borders.
    leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);
    //Allow for title and status bars.
    topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 50);
    //Open the window.
    window.open(url, "Window2",
    "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",resizable=yes,left="
    + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY="
    + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no");
}
```

Call it by replacing `window.open(twtLink,'','width=300,height=300');` in your code with `MyPopUpWin(twtLink, 300, 300);`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Again my knowledge of coding is extremely limited. How do i integrate this with my original code?

Comment: @user1736794: see my edit. If this answers your question, don't forget to come back and mark it as the answer.

Comment: I tried inserting your provided code into a new <script type="text/javascript"> ... </script> and replacing window.open(twtLink,'','width=300,height=300'); with MyPopUpWin(300, 300); however this returns an "Object not Found! page. What am i doing wrong? Thanks. Pia @NickW

Comment: Your code is not working properly in case of two LCD - popup displayed near left corner on second screen.

Comment: @kirugan One of the limitations of my code is that the popup window will appear on the primary monitor if you have more than one. What values of `width` and `height` are you passing in to `MyPopUpWin`? And when the function executes, what are the values of `leftPosition` and `rightPosition`?