# How to open flash video in new browser window in specific size?

Tags: html, flash

Can somebody provide me with some HTML/JavaScript that will let me do the following:

When I click on a link, it would:

1. Open up a new browser window to play the Flash video in a specific size (i.e. 640x480)
2. That new browser window would be centered in the computer screen.
3. If I click on the maximize window, it would resize it all to use the full screen.

Comment: Is this video online, like youtube or vimeo? Or is it local?

Comment: It's an online flash video on AWS.  That's where my co-worker placed it.

Answer (score 0):

for first question  try like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function openWin()
    {
        myWindow=window.open('','','width=640,height=480');
        myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
        myWindow.focus();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="#" onclick="openWin()">click</a>

</body>
</html>
```

for second question see this thread [Open new window on center of screen with this javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869946/open-new-window-on-center-of-screen-with-this-javascript)

for last question you can see solution at http://www.longtailvideo.com/blog/26517/using-the-browsers-new-html5-fullscreen-capabilities/