# Set parameters of width and height for link that will open in a new window with javascript?

Tags: javascript

With the following I can open a link in a new window if it has a class of "open-new-window".

```
  (function () {

    $('.new-window').click(function(){
       window.open(this.href, 'newwindow', 'width=400, height=200'); 
       return false;
     });

  })();

<a class="new-window" href="somesite.com">Link </a>
```

How can I rewrite this so the width and height of window thats created are passed by parameters in the HTML?

So I was thinking something like this:

```
 <a class="new-window" data-window-width="400" data-window-height="200" data-name=" href="somesite.com">Link</a>
```

Note - I will need to have multiple links like this on a page, each with different height and width parameters.

I also need to centre the popup but I think I can do so with this method once I have he window height and width as parameters.
[Open new window on center of screen with this javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869946/open-new-window-on-center-of-screen-with-this-javascript)

Comment: your thought looks fine to me! you need code for that?

Comment: I need to know how to set different heights and widths for each link, and for these to be set in the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `$(this).data("window-width")` or `$(this).attr("data-window-width")` with jQuery to get at the data attributes. They're not quite equivalent to each other, but unless you're planning in modifying the widths/heights in JavaScript you can consider them to be the same. If you need to modify the values, you should take some time to understand how each is affected by updating the `<a>`.

```
(function () {

  $('.new-window').click(function(){
    var window_width = $(this).data("window-width"),
      window_height = $(this).data("window-height"),
      window_name = $(this).data("name");
    window.open(this.href, window_name, 'width=' + window_width + ', height=' + window_height); 
    return false;
  });

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access `dataset` attributes via the `Element.prototype.dataset` property.

```
window.open(this.href, 'newwindow', 'width=' + this.dataset.windowWidth + ', height=' + this.dataset.windowHeight + ');
```

*Note:* hyphens are converted into camel case notation for accessing.